# How do I use parameters in a protected function into another protected function?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have used `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}`
 in `MainActivity`class to use its `data` as result of a process by the user , and I have introduced another class for showing `ProgressDialog pd;`
---->>>>

```
 public class Loading
        extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Loading() {}

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... paramVarArgs)
    {
```

///////Some Private Functions will be here needing Data value from onActivityResult/////////
            ///////////////how to use that Data value here //////////////
            return null;
        }

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void paramVoid)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(paramVoid);
        MainActivity.this.pd.dismiss();

    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        MainActivity.this.pd.setTitle("Loading App....");
        MainActivity.this.pd.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
        MainActivity.this.pd.show();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use that `data` which is the Parameter in `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` into  `protected Void doInBackground(Void... paramVarArgs){}`
How Can I Do that ? thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to do this? Why don't you remove this AsyncTask, show ProgressDialog in when startActivityForResult() and dismiss it when there is onActivityResult() ?

Comment: because I want call some private functions needing that data and these functions must be written in doInbackground() , these functions need that data value which is in  onActivityResult parameter

Comment: and these functions take times needing to show ProgressDialog pd; for the user until the tasks of these functions get finished

Comment: AsyncTask is for doing a small amount of work and exit. It is not for long running operations, so it wouldn’t be appropriate to try to pass new data into it.

Comment: And why don't start AsyncTask in onActivityResult()?

Comment: no only I want to use its input Data ( its Intent Date -> third input parameter of onActivityResult (int , int , Intent Data)

Comment: how can I use AsyncTask in OnActivityResult ?
what is the necessary code ?
@anhtuannd

Answer (score 0):

I got it WOoW

```
AsyncTask Myasytsk = new AsyncTask() {
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    MainActivity.this.systemWritedo(pathfile);

    return null;
}
         protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

             MainActivity.this.pd.dismiss();
             MainActivity.this.reboot();

         }

         protected void onPreExecute() {

             MainActivity.this.pd.setTitle("Installation....");
             MainActivity.this.pd.setMessage("Please Wait.....");
             MainActivity.this.pd.show();

         }
};
Myasytsk.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **AsyncTask class** should be like that.

```
public class Loading extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
      private MainActivity act = null;

      //this is constructor
      public Loading(MainActicity _act) {
           this.act = _act;
      }
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... paramVarArgs)
      {
            //your codes
      }
      protected Void onPostExecute(Object result) {
           //your codes
           act.pd.dismiss();
           act.reboot();
      }
}
```

You can use **AsyncTask class** in **MainActivity**.

```
private Loading loadingTask;
public ProgressDialog pd;    //your progress dialog must be public
private void DoSomething(){

                       //"this" send reference of MainActivity to Loading class
     loadingTask = new LoadingTask(this);
     loadingTask.execute(); 

}
```